# Putty Customization - Different Icons For Different Sessions?

Tags: putty

I'm looking to customize my putty sessions so I can change the icon depending on a "group" that the putty session is in. I essentially want my taskbar (windows 7) to have an icon for each group I define, but each of those icons to be different. Is there a good tool or way to do this? Thank you very much for any replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it manually.

1. Create a shortcut of putty on the desktop
2. Edit the "Target:" line in right-click properties (add `-load <session name>`)
3. press change Icon and choose your icon   -

Comment: Does this still work for you?  Doesn't seem to work for me on Windows 10.  It only seems to change the icon for the .lnk shortcut file itself.  Once you open it, the taskbar just shows the default putty.exe icon.

Answer (score 0):

I use PuTTYTray: https://puttytray.goeswhere.com/

It allows you to choose the icon in the configuration:
*Window - Behaviour - Adjust the icon*.
Then just save the session.

As a small annoyance, you don't have many options for icons, since it uses the .ico format. Therefore, I keep a copy of the original program PUTTY.EXE, if only to capture the original icon from there.

Answer (score 0):

I made a patch to PuTTy which allows you to specify a custom taskbar icon for a window/session (as opposed to an taskbar icon which is a shortcut to a session). i.e. If you have several active sessions, each one can be identified in the taskbar by it's own icon. The link below has the patch (which is pretty small) and a pre-build executable with the patch (which is against a pretty old version of PuTTy).

http://www.bradgoodman.com/puttypatch.html